# Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Russian on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

> Would you please translate the following paragraphs into Russian?
>
> - a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
> - All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
> - You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
> - There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
>     network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
> - Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!
> - Please share or like the post as much as possible. This will help it    be seen on more news feeds and it will likely be seen by more
>     interested people.
> - Please share the page and invite others to like it in order to have more committers and probably a successful launch
>
> I need them to post about [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2) in facebook pages that
>   are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
>   facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
>   more attention and so they might be seen by more people.
>
> Hint: I just want those bulleted paragraphs in Russian not more.

Comment: This is utterly offtopic

Comment: But the longer Russian -English  translations seem to be *on topic*